# bat-Script: execute command, reopen cmd and execute another command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Good morning everyone,

i try to write a script to do the following example (all in cmd):

1. execute command
2. wait for the command to be finished
3. close the cmd window and open a new one
4. execute another command
5. exit

My problem is at point 2 and 3. `exit` is not possible because the script is terminated .
And with the command `start cmd /k <command>` a new cmd instance will be opend and both commands (1 and 4) will be executed at once.

Thx in advance

**EDIT:** The requested code

```
cup chocolatey
exit  // Not working
cup all -y
pause
```

**EDIT:** The solution

```
@echo off
cup chocolatey
SCHTASKS /delete /tn "updateAll" /f
SCHTASKS /create /tn "updateAll" /tr "cmd.exe /c \"cup all -y\"" /sc ONCE /ST 00:00 /sd 01/01/1910 /RL HIGHEST
SCHTASKS /run /tn "updateAll"
EXIT
```

Comment: Batch by default waits for one command to finish before starting the next command, unless you've got a `call` or a `start /b` going. Show us your code.

Comment: the problem is that the first command upgrades chocolatey (packet manager). Afterwards the CMD-Window should be reopend again to further use chocolatey commands.

Comment: you'll `SCHTASKS` to do this....

Comment: I feel like having chocolatey update itself via a separate script would be the easiest solution. You call that script so that it opens in a separate window, that window closes, and then the rest of your code goes about its business as usual.

Comment: http://chocolatey.github.io/usage.html

Comment: `start "" /B /WAIT command` (point #1) will execute your `command` and waits for it to be finished. See my explanation here: http://superuser.com/a/908744/376602

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off

start "" /w someCommand.exe some parameters
SCHTASKS /create /tn "OnDemand" /tr "cmd.exe /c \" command parameters \"" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
SCHTASKS /Run  /TN "OnDemand"
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

This will create "OnDemand"  task and will run it through the SCHTASKS. It will start a new instance of the command prompt which will be not depending on already running cmd.exe

Comment: thats not the desired result and behavior. With `SCHTASKS` 2 seperate CMD-Instances will be opend and executed at once, I want the commands to be executed one after another

Comment: was my fault, used as you wrote above and modified my command a bit. I will edit my question with the solution. Thx man